# Store data set after call load data function Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a function `load_data`, with no input and no return, which just read data set from url and split data set. If I would like to call function `load_data()`, how can I store these two data sets if I call `load_data()` elsewhere?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are many ways to do that and it depends on code you haven't shown, but usually it is best to have the `load_data` function return something: the loaded data.

Comment: I agree with @zvone but if you really can't return anything (e.g. because of assignment requirements) you could use a global variable in which you can store the loaded data, although I don't recommend doing this.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a class for whatever you're doing with the data and have `load_data()` be a function of the class that stores the data to a variable of the class.

```
class MyDataClass:
  def __init__(self):
    self.data = None
  def load_data(self):
    self.data = # put your data stuff here
```